# Qt printing using html and QTextDocument

Tags: c++, qt

I fight with printing pdf from QTextDocument object with html format. I generate QString formatted code of html page and it works fine. To test it i make using QFile a html file which have to be printed and it look greats.
But pdf file looks completly different and i don't know why.

Code:

```
    QString html = getHtmlPrintString(FVToPrint, currentCustomer);
    QTextDocument document;
    document.setHtml(html);

    QFile qHtmlFile("D:\\Qt\\projects\\FVGeneratorV2\\fv\\"+QString::fromStdString(FVToPrint.getFVId()) +".html");
    if(qHtmlFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        qHtmlFile.write(html.toUtf8());
        qHtmlFile.close();
    }

    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::PrinterResolution);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.setPageSize(QPageSize::A4);
    QString fvname = "D:\\Qt\\projects\\FVGeneratorV2\\fv\\" + QString::fromStdString(FVToPrint.getFVId()) + ".pdf";
    printer.setOutputFileName(fvname);
    printer.setPageMargins(QMarginsF(15, 15, 15, 15));

    document.print(&printer);
```

Html file code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <style type='text/css'>table, tr, td{border: solid 1px black; border-collapse:collapse;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style='width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding: 0;'>
            <div style='float:left; border: solid 2px black; width:42%; margin-right:2%; margin-left:2%; padding:2%; height:5%;'>
                <h2><b>FV_24.01.2022_666_1_480</h2></b>
            </div>
            
            <div style='float:left; padding:2%; margin-right:2%; border: solid 2px black; width:42%; height:5%;'>
                24.01.2022
            </div>
            
            <div style='clear:both;'></div>
            
            <div style='float:left; border: solid 2px black; width:42%; margin-right:2%; margin-top:1%; margin-left:2%; padding:2%; height:15%;'>
                kunito</br> Nip: 8712314</br> Phone: 9123412</br> Email: mail@com</br>miejska 12</br>47821 krakow, Polska</br>
            </div>
            
            <div style='float:left; margin-top:1%; padding:2%; margin-right:2%; border: solid 2px black; width:42%; height:15%;'>
                Customer: </br> Name: test&nbsp</br> Nip: 12398401</br>miejska 27</br>81293 Krakow, Polska</br>
            </div>
            
            <div style='clear:both;'></div>
            
            <div style=' margin: 1% 2% 0 2%; padding:2%; border: solid 2px black; width:90.5%; height:10%;'>    Payment data: </br>online transfer</br> Account number: 8912384</br> Title:             FV_24.01.2022_666_1_480
            </div>
            
            <div style=' margin: 1% 2% 0 2%; padding:2%; width:90.5%; height:30%;'>
                <table style='width:100%;'><tr style='background-color:darkgray;' ><td>Nb.</td><td>Name</td><td>Um</td><td>Quantity</td><td>Price netto</td><td>Vat</td><td>Vat value</td><td>Price brutto</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Bulka</td><td>pcs</td><td>1</td><td>1.012</td><td>8</td><td>0.088</td><td>1.1</td></tr><tr style='background-color:darkgray;' ><td colspan='5'></td><td>Netto sum</td><td>Vat sum</td><td>Sum</td></tr><tr><td colspan='5'></td><td>1.012</td><td>0.088</td><td>1.1</td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            
            <div style=' margin: 1% 2% 0 2%; padding:2%; width:90.5%; height:5%;'>
                To pay: 1.1 zl </br> Payed: 1.1 zl
            </div>
            
            <div style=' margin: 1% 2% 0 2%; padding:2%; width:90.5%; height:5%;'>
                <div style='float:left; width: 20%; height:100%; '>
                    <p align='center'>............................</br>podpis pracownika</p>
                </div>
                <div style='float:left; width: 20%; height:100%; margin-left:50%; '>
                    <p align='center'>............................</br>podpis klienta</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How to pdf look:
[pdf printed file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16Bf6.png)

Comment: Make sure html is valid: what is `</br>` (should be `<br>`), and make sure CSS properties supported by Qt's rich text engine (borders supported for tables)

Comment: ok i will check that

Comment: I replaced ```</br>``` with ```<br>``` but still pdf is bad. It looks like the width,height and float properties didn't work correctly.  I also checked border supporting for table and it is supported.

Comment: Yes, I ment borders supported _only_ for tables. In your html divs styled with borders whish is ok for browsers but not for qt rich text. Check others carefully.

Comment: Ok. I didn't understand you well

Comment: Ok i must to change div to table and it should be good because it is the only one way to set border and float